# Comparing language loss among two types of bilinguals

Tags: multiple-comparisons, manova

I have two groups: Simultaneous and Sequential Bilinguals

I have three measures: grammatical complexity, lexical complexity, and grammatical accuracy (all are quantified differently)

I will conduct measures over nine sessions.

I think I need to do a two-way mixed anova, but I am not sure? Also, where can I just plug my data in to do this? I don't have spss?

I want to compare how both groups lose language over a 36 month period.

So, I want to look at how the values of each session compare within groups and between groups. Also, where can I find a way to justify my choice of analysis.

Thanks,

Jay

Comment: Also each group has three participants.

Comment: Do each of your groups (Simultaneous and Sequential Bilinguals) have equal sample sizes? And what kind of scale are your measures on (i.e. do they have upper and lower limits or are restricted to being whole numbers)?

Comment: Yes, each sample size is 3. Each measure is on a scale like weight, the minimum is 0 and there is no maximum. But participants are all matched on language proficiency so changes in scores should not vary dramatically within or between groups. I wish I could just put some data into a tool and just see what comes out. The challenge I am facing is that I do not care about the score, I do care about change in the score relative to each participant.

Comment: And what I care about beyond that is if there is a significant difference within each group (hope not as this would be a problem) and most importantly between groups. I want to know the difference between groups for each measure during each session and then the finally all sessions. I want to determine if there is a significant loss of language skill prevalent in one group over the other.